# Custom \special command causes unwanted whitespace

Tags: spacing, dvi

For a custom application we use DVI as an intermediate format and feed it to a converter. Our converter needs a "hint" to locate the beginning of a `\section` in the DVI file. Therefore, we modified **article.cls** to insert a custom `\special` ("foobar" in the example below) right at the beginning of a section.

Original file:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

Modified file:

```
\newcommand\section{\special{foobar}\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

Now when we use this modified class we get an unwanted extra vertical spacing before every section. The spacing is about the height of one text row. How can we avoid this?

Comment: \special gets in the way of the \addvspace in \@startsection, so the vertical space before the command isn't wrapped into the vertical space the command itself adds.  what's the \special for? -- it may be possible to add it from within the argument, by putting it after \normalfont....

Comment: Our converter uses the specials to compute something like a bounding box for each section, i.e. when it finds a "foobar" `\special` is takes the current DVI cursor position. So, basically any solution is good as long as the `\special` ends up directly above/left of the `\section`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `\special` in vertical mode leads to all kinds of pain. You want to avoid it if possible. I would add it just before typesetting the heading *in the horizontal list that contains the heading text*.

```
\let\old@sect\@sect
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \old@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{\leavevmode\special{foo}#8}}
```